# Doctrine MongoDB ODM: must one call flush() after findAndUpdate()?

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine-odm

Empirically it seems that `flush()` is not necessary after `findAndUpdate()`, I just couldn't find this explicitly stated anywhere in the Doctrine ODM/MongoDB docs (and I didn't bother to read much source code).

The [`findAndModify` docs on mongodb.org](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/findAndModify+Command) state

> This command can be used to atomically modify a document (at most one) and return it.

And [Doctrine MongoDB's `findAndUpdate()` uses MongoDB's `findAndModify`](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/find-and-update.html). So it sounds like the whole thing does indeed happen in one go, so calling `flush()` on the document manager shouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flush is only needed for writing changes to managed objects back to Mongo. Anything you do through the query builder interface will be executed directly and bypass UnitOfWork. This is especially true for updates and upserts. In the case of `findAndUpdate()`, the update should be executed in Mongo immediately, but I believe the object returned might be managed. Any changes to that document afterwards (e.g. via setter methods) would need a `flush()` if you wanted them written back to Mongo.

Also, be aware of `returnNew()` on the query builder, which corresponds to the `new` option of `findAndModify`. By default, I believe `findAndUpdate()` will return the document in its pre-updated state. You may prefer to retrieve the document in its updated state.

Comment: Much appreciated, once again. Where should I send the bitcoin tip? (Or Dwolla, or PayPal)